# Install a forked version of a repo, instead of from NPM

Tags: git, npm, package.json, git-fork

I have a project that was originally using an npm package. I now need to fork the repo, so that I can make changes to it. In my package.json, I have this line:

```
"react-calendar-timeline": "get-spiffy/react-calendar-timeline",
```

then I run npm install again but I get this error:

```
Error in ./src/Schedule.js
Module not found: 'react-calendar-timeline' in /admin-scheduler/src
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using submodule:**

You can add the forked repo as a submodule to the main repo.

```
git submodule add git@github.com:get-spiffy/react-calendar-timeline.git ./path/to/external/dependencies/directory
```

You can then modify you `package.json`,

```
"react-calendar-timeline": "file:./path/to/external/dependencies/directory/react-calendar-timeline",
```

---

**Using npm:**

The other option could be publishing the npm package. You can directly then add it to `package.json`. This resource about [scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/scoped-packages) might help.